# IntelliJ wrongly suggesting static method in Groovy @Component?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, static, private

[image]

I've got a @Component groovy class and when I create a private method IntelliJ keeps telling me to make it static. Isn't this considered a bad practice?

Another important fact is that when I want to mock this class later on I would need to mock with PowerMock and Mockito which in my opinion is a big code smell.

So the question would be, should I make my methods static or not?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about `org.springframework.stereotype.Component`? If not, could you please state the import? And is the function there pure and intellij just rightfully suggest it?

Comment: Yes that's the one I'm talking. The function is a simple void function to validate some logic

Comment: So it fine to be static because it does not modify state of your component?

Comment: I believe it should be considered a code smell cause @component will create a singleton and making it static can bring you later on problems when mocking the class. Cause if I did make it static, to mock it I would need to use PowerMock and Mockito to mock all of its methods

Answer (score 2):

> I've got a @Component groovy class and when I create a private method
> IntelliJ keeps telling me to make it static. Isn't this considered a
> bad practice?

It is.

> So the question would be, should I make my methods static or not?

No, you shouldn't.